# EF naming, is there a setting to change all field names to lower case?

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

When use EF with breezejs, seems server side should have each name starts with upper case, and on client side, use camel style, like

FirstName on EF and
firstName on client side.

I think it is not as good as all lower case, everyone can understand firstname, not necessary FirstName or firstName.

I wonder if it is strongly suggested to not use all lower case name?  If I want to use all lower case name, is there a way to tell EF (database first) to create class with all lower case name no matter what they are on the db side?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the Breeze NamingConvention is for.

See: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/naming-convention

But you may have a problem because the NamingConvention needs to be able to roundtrip your name. i.e. passing from server name to client name and back to server name needs to get back to the original name.  With your rule there is no way to get from an all lowercase name back to the original server name unless you are willing to keep a map of all previously mapped names or come up with some other heuristic.

The example below demonstrates the issue.

```
var lowerCaseNamingConvention = new breeze.NamingConvention({
  serverPropertyNameToClient: function (serverPropertyName, prop) {
     return serverPropertyName.toLowerCase();
  }

  clientPropertyNameToServer: function (clientPropertyName, prop) {
     // need to get back to original name here
     return clientPropertyName. ???
  }           
});

lowerCaseNamingConvention.setAsDefault();
```

Comment: I guess I didn't express myself well, I think it is the naming of Entity framework part, I have tables from other sources, some fields named with all lowercase, some with upper case like firstName or FirstName in their table fields. I am looking for a way to let EF to create classes (database first) with all fields in lowercase.
Just wonderring how to do that, and if it is good to do like that, or should I go to those tables and fix those field names?

Comment: I would bet that renaming in the DB itself is a poor option; someone will get pissed at you. If you were using EF6 **Code First** you could [write your own convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469439) to fix the names. But you insist on DB first ... using the designer I assume. The designer lets you rename individual properties by hand. If I were doing it, I'd probably write translation code to post-process the EDMX and do that for me automatically rather than try to catch them all by hand. **Remember to use source control :-) !!!**

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do this within your JSON serialization and deserialization. If you're using Web API you can do this. From [OdeToCode](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/25/asp-net-webapi-tip-3-camelcasing-json.aspx):

```
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

If you don't want to do this with your JSON serialization, then if you're using EF6 code first you can do some custom conventions to achieve this for your column names. Do something similar for tables.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Properties()
        .Configure(p => p.HasColumnName(p.ClrPropertyInfo.Name.ToLower()));




    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserHashHistoryConfiguration());
}
```

See [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164) on MSDN for more information on custom conventions in EF6.

Comment: Thanks, see my comment above, I think I am looking more at how to let EF to do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on why you want to change the property names on the server-side. Property names in .NET classes are expected to be PascalCase.

You're free to do as you please and name the properties as you wish in the EF mapper. It's harder to do in EF Database First; you can use the designer to map each property name exactly as you want to see it but wow is that time consuming. There are advanced techniques with T4 that might be better if your model is huge (beware: you can spend more time writing/debuggin T4 than just slogging through and mapping the property names by hand).

If you were willing to go with Code First, you could take a look at [EF 6 custom conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx) which appear to be sufficiently flexible and powerful.

You DO realize that this is not a breeze question, right? The Breeze `NamingConvention` (mentioned by others) is the proper place to make your client-side properties look the way you want them to look.

There isn't always a way to calculate the transform; sometimes you just have to provide a dictionary in your `NamingConvention`.

However, you seem to want to handle this by remaking the classes on the server. That (as you've noted) is harder and/or tedious. There is nothing Breeze can do about that.

p.s.: using JSON.NET configuration to try to cope with this during serialization **will not work**. You want property names that you can reference in queries and JSON.NET does nothing to morph the property names mentioned in query strings.